# $ref doesn't work when using multiple nested files while building swagger documentation

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I'm not sure if I'm way off track here but I've been messing around with Swagger the past few days and trying to set up my documentation in a way that I can separate the documentation into smaller, more manageable files. However, what I've found is when I try to `$ref` a file inside of another file that I have already used `$ref` on, it seems to be not working.

I've set up a page with Swagger-UI running so you can see http://jer-k.github.io/swagger-docs-testing/swagger-ui/?url=http://jer-k.github.io/swagger-docs-testing/docs/api.swagger.yaml (repo is https://github.com/jer-k/swagger-docs-testing)

If you look in [api.swagger.yaml](https://github.com/jer-k/swagger-docs-testing/blob/master/docs/api.swagger.yaml#L28-L29) at the first path, I'm using

`schema:
  $ref: "./schema/trade-report.yaml"`

And if you view the 'TradeReport' section in Swagger-UI you can see that the schema is properly loaded as a parameter.

Then if you look in [api.swagger.yaml](https://github.com/jer-k/swagger-docs-testing/blob/master/docs/api.swagger.yaml#L40-L41) in the second path I'm loading it through a `$ref`

`"/payments/calculate":
  $ref: './calculate.yaml'`

And if we look in [calculate.yaml](https://github.com/jer-k/swagger-docs-testing/blob/master/docs/calculate.yaml#L7-L8) I'm referencing the trade report again

`schema:
  $ref: "./schema/trade-report.yaml"`

But viewing the calculate path under Payments in Swagger-UI the parameter is not correctly set. It has `Data Type: http://jer-k.github.io/swagger-docs-testing/docs/./calculate.yaml#./schema/trade-report.yaml`

I'm really confused as to why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

@TheJer, ok, I learned more in the past 24 hours. So writing back to you :)

There is an existing issue with Swagger-UI resolving nested $ref. I came across the same issue and have logged issue [#1943](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/1943) for the same. Hopefully things will start working once the issue is resolved.

Comment: Just to note, I also commented https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/1674#issuecomment-157908860 quite awhile ago. I guess I should have updated this question. It seems like 2.1.4 was released recently, I'll have to give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

@TheJer try restricting the use of `$ref` to only schema definitions and check it out.

Comment: Please provide some details as to why this will work so other users of the site can better understand your answer.